# Big theta notation Let P(n) = 1/3*n^5- 10*n^3+7*n-25.Formally prove that P(n) = theta (n^5).

Tags: asymptotics

First I tried to get the C2 by this:
n=1

1/3*n^5- 10*n^3+7*n-25 <= 1/3*n^5+7*n^5 = 22/3*n^5  , C2=22/3 (I removed all the negative terms and multiplied the positive so I can get the max value, is this correct?)

And then I tried to get the min value by this:
1/3*n^5- 10*n^3+7*n-25 >= - 10*n^3-25*n^3= -35*n^3 (Removed all the positive and multiplied negative,  but then the C1=-35 is negative too, which is clearly wrong. How shoud I solve this?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To show it's big theta, just need positive constants A,B so that for sufficiently large n, $An^5 \le P(n) \le Bn^5.$ Since only need for sufficiently large n, there's really no need to be as careful as you seem to be doing.

Comment: But how do I find the A,B,n...  ?

Comment: Use that $\lim P(n)/n^5 = 1/3$

Comment: Trying to do it straight from the definition is fine too.  Again... *we don't need tight bounds!*  It is a waste of time trying to get the tightest bounds here.  It should be clear that $\frac{1}{3}n^5-10n^3+7n-25\leq \frac{1}{3}n^5+7n^5$ since subtracting fewer things of course makes it bigger, and since adding bigger things instead of smaller things makes it bigger.  Now, for the other side... $\frac{1}{6}n^5+\frac{1}{6}n^5-10n^3-25n^3\leq \frac{1}{3}n^5-10n^3+7n-25$ by similar logic.  Now, notice that we were able to split the $n^5$ term in two.

Comment: Now... can we eventually reach a point where $\frac{1}{6}n^5-35n^3\geq 0$?  With large enough $n$ we should be able to.  Can you find it and finally finish the problem?  Again, we *don't need to be tight with our bounds*.